# Is my proof that $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=1$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I'm doing an exercise where $(u_n)$ is a numerical sequence which is decreasing and strictly positive.While $(u_n)$ is a numerical sequence which is decreasing and strictly positive, then $(u_n)$ is convergent and its limit is positive which we symbolise by $l$. Assume that $l\ne 0$.

I have to prove that  $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=1$. I'm not sure if my proof is correct or not. Can you please check it? Thank you very much!
Please excuse my English. We don't study Maths in English.

Let $\varepsilon\in ]0;l[$.

So $\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,n>N\Longrightarrow |u_n-l|<\varepsilon$

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such as $n>N$. We also have $n+1>n>N$.
Then:

$|u_{n+1}-u_n|=|(u_{n+1}-l)-(u_n-l)|\le |u_{n+1}-l|+|u_n-l|<2\varepsilon$    $(1)$

And we have $|u_n-l|<\varepsilon$ so $0<l-\varepsilon<u_n<l+\varepsilon$ and so whe have $0<\dfrac{1}{u_n}<\dfrac{1}{l-\varepsilon}$    $(2)$

Then $(1)\times (2)$ gives:

$\left|\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}-1\right|<\dfrac{2\varepsilon}{l-\varepsilon}$

We put $\varepsilon '=\dfrac{2\varepsilon}{l-\varepsilon}>0$. Then $\varepsilon=\dfrac{l\varepsilon '}{2+\varepsilon '}>0$.

While $\varepsilon '>0$ then $\dfrac{\varepsilon '}{2+\varepsilon '}<1$ and because $l>0$ we have then $\varepsilon=\dfrac{l\varepsilon '}{2+\varepsilon '}<l$

And so $\forall\varepsilon '\in\mathbb{R}^{+*},\,\exists\varepsilon\in ]0,l[,\,\varepsilon=\dfrac{l\varepsilon '}{2+\varepsilon '}$ and so $\varepsilon '$ covers $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$ where $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$ is the set of strictly positive real numbers. As a result we have then:$$\forall\varepsilon '\in\mathbb{R}^{+*},\,\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\, n>N\Longrightarrow\left|\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}-1\right| <\varepsilon '$$

And so  $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=1$

**Edit**: $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$ is the set of strictly positive real numbers.

**Edit2**: Assume that $l\ne 0$.

Comment: Is the only condition that $u_n$ is decreasing and strictly positive, or os there some other condition? Because decreasing and strictly positive isn't enough: $u_n\frac{1}{n!}$. If it $u_n$ is bounded below by a positive real, then it is true...

Comment: I got a little but confused in the last second paragraph. What is R^+* ?

Comment: Decreasing and strictly positive is the only condition we have.
I'm afraid I didn't understand correctly what you said.
Anyway. A theorem says that each positive and decreasing sequence is convergent, and a theorem says that each convergent sequence is bounded. $u_n=\dfrac{1}{n!}$ is in fact decreasing and positive and bounded: positive and less than 1. And we have $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\dfrac{n}{n+1}$ which limit is 1.
Thank you for your post!

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$ is the set of strictly positive real numbers.

Comment: @Scientifica: In Thomas' example, $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \dfrac{n!}{(n+1)!} = \dfrac{1}{n+1}$, whose limit is $0$. Moreover, in the english language "positive" already means $>0$, so that $\mathbb R^+$ is enough to denote the set you want.

Comment: Oh what a mistake!
Well I think I' got the error. Well in my post $l\ge 0$ but I considered it as $l>0$.
So we must have an additional condition: we must suppose that $l\ne 0$. Whith this condition is then the proof correct?

Comment: @FPE Several English-language books I've seen use $\mathbb R^+$ for "non-negative," but those books use $\mathbb R^{++}$ for positive.

Comment: That other condition is equivalent to what I wrote: that $u_n$ is bounded below by a positive number. @Scientifica

Comment: Yes you're right @Thomas.
Thank you everyone!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Oh, never seen such a notation before. I guess this depends on author's religion! Anyway, I don't see the logic in this: reading $+$ and thinking "non negative", but that's because my mind is lazy.

Comment: I'm Moroccan. In Morocco we use Frensh's notations.
Let $D$ a non empty set.

$D^*=D-\{0\}$

$D^+=\{x\in D,\,x\ge 0\}$

Comment: It is possible to give a quite brief $\epsilon$-$N$ proof of the fact that if the limit of the $u_n$ is positive, then the ratio approaches $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm sorry I didn't understand this: $\epsilon$-$N$

Comment: I mean a "formal" proof like yours, but less complicated.  I find your argument difficult to read.

Comment: Ah ok. I'd really like it if you share a less complicated proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an exercise, we give a detailed argument  directly from the definition. Suppose that the sequence $(u_n)$ has limit $a\gt 0$. We want to show that for any $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is an $N$ such that 
$$1-\epsilon\lt \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\le 1\tag{1}$$
if $n\gt N$. Note that 
$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\ge \frac{a}{u_n},$$ so it suffices to make $\frac{a}{u_n}\gt 1-\epsilon$. This will be the case automatically if $\epsilon\ge 1$, so we may suppose that $\epsilon\lt 1$.

For $0\lt \epsilon\lt 1$ we have 
$$\frac{a}{u_n}\gt 1-\epsilon \quad\text{iff}\quad u_n \lt \frac{a}{1-\epsilon}   \quad\text{iff}\quad u_n-a\lt \frac{a\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}.$$

Since the sequence $(u_n)$ converges to $a$, there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$, then $u_n-a\lt \frac{a\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$. For any such $n$, Inequality (1) will hold.

**Remark:** Informally, this is simpler than it looks. We can scale the sequence $(u_n)$ so that it has limit $1$. That does not change ratios.

Comment: Thank you very much for your post! Yes it's much simpler.
Please I didn't understand what to "scale a sequence" means. Please can you explain it?

Comment: Apologies, I used an informal term. Divide each $u_n$ by the limit $a$. So define $v_n$ by $v_n=\frac{u_n}{a}$. Then the limit of the $v_n$ is $1$, and $\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}=\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$. It is easier to visualize a sequence that has limit $1$ than a sequence with limit $a$, it is more concrete, and the inequalities required are intuitively clear.

Comment: If you think so... It's the same for me.
Thank you for your clarification!

Answer (score 7):

Not really an answer to your question, but an alternative approach.

If $u_n\to \ell_1$ and $v_n\to \ell_2$ with $l_1\neq 0$, then $\frac{v_n}{u_n}\to \frac{\ell_2}{\ell_1}$ as a general rule. So if $v_n=u_{n+1}$...

Comment: Yes!
Well in my post we have:
$$|u_{n+1}-u_n|<2\varepsilon$$
And so $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}u_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}u_n=l\in\mathbb{R}$.

If $l\ne 0$ then using this rule we get:$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\dfrac{l}{l}=1$$

Comment: The fact that $u_n\to \ell$ implies $u_{n+1}\to\ell$ is easy to prove directly from the definition of limit, you don't need anything about $|u_{n+1}-u_n|$. So all you need is this general properties about convergent series.

Comment: Basically, this theorem is true for *any* non-zero sequence with non-zero limit.

Comment: Yes you're right!